# QT strange GUI Components: Tabs?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I saw once someone making the GUI in QT and he had something I have never seen until now: They looked like big buttons one after another and when you clicked on them, the buttons below were going down, making space for the dialog or tab. It was like, if you click on the button "Draw", suddenly below the button a tab or a dialog or ??? appeared with all the GUI components (radio buttons, listboxes, ...) that you need for draw. When you clicked on another button, this GUI disappeared to make space for another GUI. Does anybody know what it is?

Comment: It seems to be Toolbox widget

Answer (score 1):

Qt does support tabs.

They are actually different widgets you can switch from in the same window.

Here you can find an example on how to use then: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-ui-components-tabwidget.html

Inside a tab it's just like a normal widget.